# Exceptions often cause crash when using Xamarin.Insights

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin

When I use Xamarin Insight, very ordinary exceptions (like NullReferenceException) cause app crash, even though they're in a try block thus supposed to be caught.

When I remove the following line from FinishedLaunching, it goes back to normal. It catches all exceptions.

Any idea what's wrong?

```
Xamarin.Insights.Initialize(ApiKey);
```

Here is an example.

```
try
{
    PerformSegue("NON-EXISTING-SEGUE", this); // will throw an exception
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
}
```

I don't even use Xamarin.Insights to report the exception, but still it causes the  app to crash. When I remove Xamarin.Insights, it catches the exception.

Comment: doesn't catching the exception not let the application crash where Insights can pick it up?

Comment: @kenny It should catch the exception, that's where I use Xamarin Insight to report the exception if I wanted to, otherwise, if it's not wrapped in a try/catch block, it should cause an app crash. However, Xamarin is supposed to report a crash report before the app dies.

Answer (score 1):

This is the old issue but I think it's still can be useful

Put this in `AppDelegate.cs`:

```
[DllImport ("libc")]
private static extern int sigaction (Signal sig, IntPtr act, IntPtr oact);

enum Signal {
    SIGBUS = 10,
    SIGSEGV = 11
}

static void EnableCrashReporting ()
{
    IntPtr sigbus = Marshal.AllocHGlobal (512);
    IntPtr sigsegv = Marshal.AllocHGlobal (512);

    // Store Mono SIGSEGV and SIGBUS handlers
    sigaction (Signal.SIGBUS, IntPtr.Zero, sigbus);
    sigaction (Signal.SIGSEGV, IntPtr.Zero, sigsegv);

    // Enable crash reporting libraries
    EnableCrashReportingUnsafe ();

    // Restore Mono SIGSEGV and SIGBUS handlers            
    sigaction (Signal.SIGBUS, sigbus, IntPtr.Zero);
    sigaction (Signal.SIGSEGV, sigsegv, IntPtr.Zero);
}

static void EnableCrashReportingUnsafe ()
{
    // Run your crash reporting library initialization code here--

    // Verify in documentation that your library of choice
    // installs its sigaction hooks before leaving this method.

    Xamarin.Insights.Initialize(ApiKey);
}
```

Call `EnableCrashReporting ()` in the beginning of `FinishedLaunching` method.
Wrap this call in `#if !DEBUG` directive if you want.

You can read more about this problem at [xamarin forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/931/how-to-prevent-ios-crash-reporters-from-crashing-monotouch-apps)

Answer (score 0):

you can't break out of a try/catch statement in c# so it sounds like something else is going on, you haven't left much information or example code so the only thing I could guess is that another thread, possibly one inside insights, is crashing and that thread is triggered by something in your try/catch